# I can't figure out why Install-WindowsFeature is timing out

Tags: powershell

Title.  I can't seem to get this to work and I'm miffed as to why.  Windows 2012R2 Data Center.  The below source is from the install.wim file directly from an install CD.  It errors out with the following error:

```
The server could not update the provided feature files in the time allowed
```

Below is the code, note it shows which features I'm trying to install.  In theory this shouldn't be reaching out to windows update (I think).  OTOH, I'm a developer and not a windows admin so I honestly don't know what the underlying behavior is supposed to be.  It's the reason why I'm here, at this point I've tried all I can think of.

Under what circumstances does this error occur and how do I go about solving it?

```
$features = Get-Features
$source = "wim:C:\WindowsCore\install.wim:4"

Install-WindowsFeature -Name $features -IncludeManagementTools -Source $source -WarningAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null

function Get-Features {
  return [string[]] @(
      'FileAndStorage-Services'
      'Storage-Services'
      'Web-Server'
      'Web-WebServer'
      'Web-Common-Http'
      'Web-Default-Doc'
      'Web-Dir-Browsing'
      'Web-Http-Errors'
      'Web-Static-Content'
      'Web-Http-Redirect'
      'Web-Health'
      'Web-Http-Logging'
      'Web-Log-Libraries'
      'Web-ODBC-Logging'
      'Web-Request-Monitor'
      'Web-Http-Tracing'
      'Web-Performance'
      'Web-Stat-Compression'
      'Web-Dyn-Compression'
      'Web-Security'
      'Web-Filtering'
      'Web-Basic-Auth'
      'Web-Client-Auth'
      'Web-Digest-Auth'
      'Web-Cert-Auth'
      'Web-IP-Security'
      'Web-Url-Auth'
      'Web-Windows-Auth'
      'Web-App-Dev'
      'Web-Net-Ext'
      'Web-Net-Ext45'
      'Web-ASP'
      'Web-Asp-Net'
      'Web-Asp-Net45'
      'Web-CGI'
      'Web-ISAPI-Ext'
      'Web-ISAPI-Filter'
      'Web-Includes'
      'Web-WebSockets'
      'Web-Ftp-Server'
      'Web-Ftp-Service'
      'Web-Mgmt-Tools'
      'Web-Mgmt-Console'
      'Web-Mgmt-Compat'
      'Web-Metabase'
      'Web-Lgcy-Mgmt-Console'
      'Web-Lgcy-Scripting'
      'Web-WMI'
      'Web-Scripting-Tools'
      'Web-Mgmt-Service'
      'NET-Framework-Features'
      'NET-Framework-Core'
      'NET-Framework-45-Features'
      'NET-Framework-45-Core'
      'NET-Framework-45-ASPNET'
      'NET-WCF-Services45'
      'NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45'
      'NET-WCF-TCP-PortSharing45'
      'RSAT'
      'RSAT-Feature-Tools'
      'RSAT-SMTP'
      'RSAT-SNMP'
      'FS-SMB1'
      'SMTP-Server'
      'SNMP-Service'
      'User-Interfaces-Infra'
      'Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra'
      'Server-Gui-Shell'
      'PowerShellRoot'
      'PowerShell'
      'PowerShell-V2'
      'PowerShell-ISE'
      'WAS'
      'WAS-Process-Model'
      'WAS-Config-APIs'
      'WoW64-Support'
    )
}
```

Comment: I would start by specifying a log and not redirecting output to null so you can actually see what it's doing and where it's failing.  I mean, it could be prompting you for input and you wouldn't know, and some features require a reboot to complete installation.  I'd also probably specify the top level features I wanted and use the `-IncludeAllSubFeature` switch to get it to walk the tree if I knew that's what I needed.  I would also restrict a single execution to a single area at a time.  Installing IIS, RSAT, and .Net all at once in arbitrary order seems like a very bad idea.

Comment: Have you tried disabling the internet to make sure it's not reaching out to Windows Update silently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also tryed to use the Install-WindowsFeature cmdlet to install several features in a setup. I ended using **dism** because it seems to be less error-prone. You could at least give it a try and maybe get a more detailed error message. Here is the script:

```
$featuresToInstall = ('FileAndStorage-Services','Storage-Services','Web-Server','Web-WebServer','Web-Common-Http','Web-Default-Doc','Web-Dir-Browsing','Web-Http-Errors',
'Web-Static-Content','Web-Http-Redirect','Web-Health','Web-Http-Logging','Web-Log-Libraries','Web-ODBC-Logging','Web-Request-Monitor',
'Web-Http-Tracing','Web-Performance','Web-Stat-Compression','Web-Dyn-Compression','Web-Security','Web-Filtering','Web-Basic-Auth',
'Web-Client-Auth','Web-Digest-Auth','Web-Cert-Auth','Web-IP-Security','Web-Url-Auth','Web-Windows-Auth','Web-App-Dev','Web-Net-Ext',
'Web-Net-Ext45','Web-ASP','Web-Asp-Net','Web-Asp-Net45','Web-CGI','Web-ISAPI-Ext','Web-ISAPI-Filter','Web-Includes','Web-WebSockets',
'Web-Ftp-Server','Web-Ftp-Service','Web-Mgmt-Tools','Web-Mgmt-Console','Web-Mgmt-Compat','Web-Metabase','Web-Lgcy-Mgmt-Console','Web-Lgcy-Scripting',
'Web-WMI','Web-Scripting-Tools','Web-Mgmt-Service','NET-Framework-Features','NET-Framework-Core','NET-Framework-45-Features','NET-Framework-45-Core',
'NET-Framework-45-ASPNET','NET-WCF-Services45','NET-WCF-HTTP-Activation45','NET-WCF-TCP-PortSharing45','RSAT','RSAT-Feature-Tools','RSAT-SMTP',
'RSAT-SNMP','FS-SMB1','SMTP-Server','SNMP-Service','User-Interfaces-Infra','Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra','Server-Gui-Shell','PowerShellRoot','PowerShell',
'PowerShell-V2','PowerShell-ISE','WAS','WAS-Process-Model','WAS-Config-APIs','WoW64-Support')

# Remove any feature that is not available to prevent dism failures. MSMQ-Container for example is only available 
# on Windows 7 but not on Windows Server 2008 R2. 
$availableFeatures = dism /online /Get-Features
$featuresToRemove = @()
$featuresToInstall | % { if (-not ($availableFeatures | Select-String ('{0}$' -f $_) -Quiet)) { $featuresToRemove += $_} }
$featuresToInstall = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $featuresToInstall -DifferenceObject $featuresToRemove | select -ExpandProperty InputObject

$dismParameter = @('/online', '/Enable-Feature', ($featuresToInstall | % { '/FeatureName:{0}' -f $_ }), '/NoRestart', '/all')

$output = dism @dismParameter

# throw an error if dism wasn't successful
if ($global:LastExitCode -ne 0)
{
    throw 'Error while installing Windows Features. {0}' -f ($output | Select-String '\.log$')
}
```

The Script also validates whether the feature is available to install using dism and removes them in that case (you can check $featuresToRemove).

Answer (score 0):

In a non core installation of Windows server 2 features are not present, one of them is net-framework-core (i forgot which other one it is), thats why you point to the source in the wim like the MS kb states, but this fails most of the times.
Instead of pointing the source to the wimfile you should point it to the \sources\sxs location of your installation medium, this always does the trick for me (you can also point to a network location with the files)